# Projector onto states with $N$ particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, operators, many-body

In my statistical mechanics textbook I have run across the following expression regarding a system of $N$ particles:

$$ \hat{P}(N) =  \theta( N - \hat{N} + 1/2) - \theta( \hat{N}- N + 1/2) $$

(with : $N$ the number of particles, $\hat{N}$ the particle number operator ,$\theta(x)$ the Heaviside step function)

This expression is supposed to be the projector onto the states of $N$ particles, but I am completely failing to see that.

If we work in the eigenbasis of $\hat{N}$ then we can consider it as a diagonal matrix of natural numbers, if I then try to evaluate $\hat{P}(N)$ by the given definition ("matrix heaviside") I don't find a projector at all... What am I missing here?

Comment: In the eigenbasis of $N$, $P(N)=1$ when $N=\hat{N}$ and 0 otherwise, so it is a projector.

Comment: huh? for elements $N = \hat{N}$ don't you get $\theta(1/2) - \theta(1/2) = 0$ ? @MengCheng

Comment: The function ${1\over 2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \exp(i(\hat N -N)\phi) $ is zero for integer eigenvalues, except for *N*, where it is 1.

Comment: Which book, author, page...?

Comment: I also think this is wrong. I'd say that for example $\hat P(N):=1-\left(\theta(N-\hat N)  + \theta(\hat N-N)\right)$ is a possible expression for the projector on the $N$-particle subspace (of the respective Fock space) in terms of the $\theta$-function. With the convention that $\theta(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and $\theta(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As your commentators suggest, your text is unfriendly and sloppy: incorrect. You are meant to shift Heaviside's step function by a $1/2$ unit in both coordinates, to end up with an [antisymmetric step function around zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Zero_argument); instead, work out the expression that works this way,
$$
\hat P(N)= 1+  \operatorname{sgn}(N-\hat N)~\operatorname{sgn}(\hat N - N)  ,
$$
[where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=0$, so it vanishes acting on eigenvectors of $\hat N$ with eigenvalues everywhere, except at the origin, eigenvalues *N* of $\hat N$.